# What state is my SQL server database in when msdeploy fails on user creation?

Tags: sql-server, msdeploy, webdeploy

I am using msdeploy (version 2) to transfer a database from machine A to machine B.

On in the database on machine A there are some users that do not exist on machine B, thus the transfer (partially) fails with the message:

```
Error Code: ERROR_SQL_EXECUTION_FAILURE
More Information: An error occurred during execution of the database script. 
The error occurred between the following lines of the script: "3" and "5". 
The verbose log might have more information about the error. 
The command started with the following: "CREATE USER [someDomain\someUser] FOR LOGIN [someDomain" 
Windows NT user or group 'someDomain\someUser' not found. 
Check the name again. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=178587
```

The database seems to be transfered, except for the user creation. Does anyone know what state the database is in after this failure?

Is there any way I can transfer the database without the users (or better without specific users) using msdeploy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web Deploy uses SMO (SQL Management Objects) to script out and apply the scripts for SQL databases, and exposes most of the SMO settings with the dbfullsql provider (so, most of these options: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.transfer_properties.aspx). If you want to skip the users due to this kind of login-not-exists or user-not-found error, you should be able to do this by adding the scripting option: copyAllUsers=false to the source of the sync. For example:

msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:dbfullsql="Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=MySourceDb;User Id=localUser;Password=LocalPass",copyAllUsers=false -dest:dbfullsql="Data Source=RemoteSQLServer;Initial Catalog=MyDestDb;User Id=remoteUser;Password=RemotePass"

Incidentally, I am surprised you note the db appears to have been sync'd - I would expect this is not actually the case. If you have the permissions for it, Web Deploy will create the database if it did not already exist when it initially tries to make the connection, but your failure occurred very early in the script execution, and I believe Web Deploy dbfullsql syncs are transacted by default (the db creation is separate from the script execution and is not transacted). Thus the db may exist where it did not pre-sync, but I wouldn't expect the data to be present in it.

Comment: To your last point: You are right. I had already restored the database from a backup file before attempting to sync. There will be no objects in the database when syncing to a database that is not yet created. Thus the state of the database will be: created but containing no objects.

Comment: Although your solution is a solution to this problem generally it does not solve my problem since one the users is used to create some roles. But I think that is most likely another problem.